# How to convert/transform linear programming problems

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Converting an LP to a standard form requires transforming both objective and constraints. Is this the same as converting a maximization problem to a minimization problem (vice-versa)?

Some texts say to transform a maximization problem to a minimization problem, we need to multiply the objective by -1 which confuses me with the standard form transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Convert any LP to standard form $$\min_x cx \text{ s.t. } x\in \text{ some polyhedron}$$
involves converting both the objective and the constraints. That is make the objective a minimization problem, change all inequalities to equality, change all free variables to a difference of two nonnegative variables and making all negative variables nonnegative.

To convert a maximization problem to a minimization problem involves changing only the objective (normally the constraints are in standard form) and the relationship is such that $$\max_x cx \ \text{ s.t.} \ x\in  \text{some polyhedron}$$
is equivalent to
$$-\min_x -cx \ \text{ s.t.} \ x\in  \text{some polyhedron}$$
conversely converting from
$$\min_x cx \ \text{ s.t.} \ x\in  \text{some polyhedron}$$
to
$$\max_x -cx \ \text{ s.t.} \ x\in  \text{some polyhedron}$$