# An Example of KKT Problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I tried using KKT sufficient condition on the problem $$\min_{x\in X} \langle g, x \rangle + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ln x_i \text{ s.t. }  \sum_{i=i}^n x_i = 1,
 \text{ where } X:= \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n | x_i >0, \forall i=1,\ldots, n\}.$$

Upon solving:

- Primal feasibility: $\sum x_i = 1$
- Dual feasibility: $g + \sum (\ln x + 1) + u(\sum x-1)=0.$

Textbook's solution: $x=e^{-g_t}/\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-g_k}.$ Are there any better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the KKT conditions I would always recommend writing things out variable by variable, it often makes things a lot clearer.

So by the Lagrangian part of the KKT conditions we have:
$$
g_{i} + \ln(x_{i}) + 1 + u = 0.
$$
Solving for $\ln(x_{i})$ it should be obvious that
$$
\ln(x_{i}) = -g_{i} - 1 - u.
$$
Hence we conclude that
$$
x_{i} = e^{-g_{i} - 1 - u}
$$
But remember from our primal feasibility condition we must have:
$$
\sum x_{k} = \sum e^{-g_{k} - (1+u)} = \frac{\sum e^{-g_{k}}}{e^{1+u}}  = 1.
$$
I am just using standard properties of the exponential here, nothing special. Thus we conclude that:
$$
e^{1+u} = \sum e^{-g_{k}}
$$
Plugging this back into our formula for $x_{i}$ we find that
$$
x_{i} = e^{-g_{i} - 1 - u} = \frac{e^{-g_{i}}}{e^{1+u}} = \frac{e^{-g_{i}}}{\sum e^{-g_{k}}}
$$
Of course, note that you actually have $n$ inequality constraints to consider when computing the Lagrangian as you are optimising over the simplex, but in this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: I forgot to find the gradient of the equality constraint; mistake.

Comment: Could you share your idea to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4470777/how-to-convert-transform-linear-programming-problems)?